# faces not fully drawing and disappearing

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, shader, opentk

im trying to learn opengl and when i use depth test the faces slowly disappear im not sure what's happening and i can't find anything online

[image]

drawing code:

```
            GLHelper.Clear();
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

            shader.Use();

            shader.SetMatrix("projection", Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver2, (float)Width / (float)Height, 0.01f, 1000.0f));
            shader.SetMatrix("view", Matrix4.LookAt(new Vector3(0,0,10),new Vector3(),Vector3.UnitY));
            shader.SetMatrix("transform",Matrix4.CreateRotationY((float)time));
            mesh.Draw();

            SwapBuffers();
```

mesh.draw:

```
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(2);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, IBO);
            GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);

            GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(1);
            GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

shader code:

```
#version 440 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;
uniform  mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

out vec4 fragcolor;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * transform * vec4(position,1.0);

 //temp
 fragcolor = color;
}
```

Comment: Do you clear the depth buffer? `GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit)`

Comment: Rabbid76 oh i  guess not GLHelper.clear was set to GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit |ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit) lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test), then you've to clear the depth buffer beside the color buffer.

```
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
```

Since depth value of the fragment is tested against the corresponding  depth value in the buffer, the depth buffer has to be cleared at the begin of the frame.